# extracting families with their representatives and number of repetition

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

There is a matrix:

```
{{1,1,1},{1,2,1},{2,1,1},{-2,-1,-1},{1,1,-2},{1,-2,2},{2,1,-2},{1,-2,2},{-2,2,1},{1,2,2},{2,2,2}}
```

How we can extract another matrix which elements are positive and be as below:

```
extractedmatrix={{1,1,1,1},{1,2,1,4},{1,2,2,4},{2,2,2,1}}.
```

The fourth column is related to the number of rows which are similar just in positive elements and without respect of permutation. For example here there is a family with four members. Because `{1,-2,2}` is repeated twice.

```
{1,-2,2},{2,1,-2},{1,-2,2},{-2,2,1},{1,2,2}
```

we show this family with their representative which has positive elements: `{1,2,2}`

Comment: Does this do the job? `Flatten /@ Tally[Sort /@ Abs[lst]]`

Comment: Wonderful, but there is a little problem:  `{1, 2, 2, 5}` it must be `{1, 2, 2, 4}` I think I have to devote a stage to remove the repeated row?! and after that I should apply your recommend.

Comment: `Flatten /@ Tally[Sort /@ Abs[DeleteDuplicates@lst]]`?

Comment: I have never seen `Tally` function. It is amazing!!!.